# read /write html to/from slide of Powerpoint presentation

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

Is it possible to get slide html of PPT in C#.

and also how can we crate new slide using html while creating presentation using interop?

Answer (score 0):

You can read from PPT file and get the text out of each slide, see below for an example :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application PowerPoint_App = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentations multi_presentations = PowerPoint_App.Presentations;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation presentation = multi_presentations.Open(@"C:\PPT\myPowerpoint.pptx");
            string presentation_text = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < presentation.Slides.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (var item in presentation.Slides[i+1].Shapes)
                {
                    var shape = (PowerPoint.Shape)item;
                    if (shape.HasTextFrame == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                    {
                        if (shape.TextFrame.HasText == MsoTriState.msoTrue)
                        {
                            var textRange = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;
                            var text = textRange.Text;
                            presentation_text += text+" ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            PowerPoint_App.Quit();
            Console.WriteLine(presentation_text);
        }
```

Comment: Thats what i am doing currently.but the problem is,all the alignments and font styles are ommited

Comment: whats the way to preserve the shape formatting(specially for text shapes)

Comment: Read the formatting of each paragraph within each textrange and translate that into HTML.  It'll take a LOT of work, far more than anyone can supply in a few snippets of code here, but we can help with it if you run into specific problems.

Comment: You're probably well off turning paragraph formatting into <p style="blabla">text</p> and inline formatting into <div style="blabla">text</div>. The rest is a matter of mapping properties such as Font.Bold to css font-weight. Things that don't have a css pendant, you can simply add as custom attributes, for example -msoLanguage.